# Updating a pointers value update what it's pointing to?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a pointer to a struct named sp.

```
struct thestruct *sp_pointer = NULL;

sp_pointer = sp;
```

This stuct has a field called units. i.e. `sp->units`

if I were to do `sp_ponter->units = sp_pointer->units + 100;`

would this update the value in sp->units?

Comment: Can't you write two lines of code to figure that out?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Why don't you check it with the help of the code?

Comment: "Try it and see" is usually not the best way to understand C code. Let's not encourage the epidemic of "my compiler does X, therefore all compilers should do X".

Comment: While I agree about trying is a bad idea in C, this question show signigficant lack of basic concepts. You need to get the whole picture. This you will not get this from asking particular questions here. Instead read a good and modern book (don't use the K&R classic ).

Comment: @trentcl In this particular case, trying it out could shed a great deal of light. OP would be left with two options, which they could then inquire about if they really really want to be sure some behaviour is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Perhaps there is more than one way to interpret the idea "try and see". On one side is "hit and hope" and on the other side is "try my hopefully informed solution." How the devil can you progress without "trying the code" - especially in the minefield of pointers in C?

Comment: Sorry @WeatherVane I disagree with your sentiment. That is how you learn, compile, step into it, debug it. All too often SO is more of a one-stop shop for laziness and get tuition for nothing. That question by the OP exhibited laziness on grand scale. When I started out in C programming more than 15yrs ago, there was no SO, just lots of research and reading. Today, people are taking SO for granted.

Comment: MCVE + 'why did this update the value in sp->units?' : OK.  MCVE + 'why did this not update the value in sp->units?'; OK.  Two lines of code and 'would this update the value in sp->units?' : no effort demonstrated and very much not OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I were to do sp_ponter->units = sp_pointer->units + 100;
>
> would this update the value in sp->units?

Yes, it would. `sp_pointer` is pointing to same memory as `sp` after your assignment. Granted both pointers are of same type, what you have should be ok.

Comment: Frankly speaking, you should't have written this answer for OP. Let OP toil on his own first(rest depends on you)!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Frankly I don't agree. C isn't a "try and see" language. That something worked for the OP doesn't mean is correct. So if you have a doubt, better do research and find out.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: OP apparently lacks basic knowledge. She will not gain this by asking about particular aspects of the syntax. Instead he needs to get the whole picture. This requires reading a book or (at least) following a comprehensive tutorial.

Comment: 'C isn't a "try and see" language' - aparently not, it's a 'Get free tuition from SO contributors' language :(

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: Just a comment. No answer at all. Sorry, but the question really shows not even a little effort learning himself. Just Youtube: "Show me what I have to think." That's not how learning works.